# destroying shadow DrawLayout

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer, toolbar, android-toolbar

The following image shows there is a shadow on my toolbar.

How can I remove this shadow and place my menu just under the toolbar?

[image]

This is my toolbar code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#2196F3"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:textDirection="rtl"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

this is my Slide-Menu code:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/my_drawerlayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- your content layout -->
<include layout="@layout/activity_list"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_navigation"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

Comment: What shadow are you referring to?

Comment: I did not understand your question...sory

Comment: Move the `Toolbar` to the "Slide-Menu code", inside the `RelativeLayout` XML, but outside the `DrawerLayout`, and align it to the top, with the `DrawerLayout` below it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yourDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: I believe the question is asking to put the drawer under the toolbar as well as remove the shadow